# Ionic / Firebase app slow to establish connection after being in the background

Tags: firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I have an Ionic app built with Firebase and Angular.

I'm having a problem where when a user returns to the app after it being idle, and they swipe down to refresh the feed, it sometimes takes 30 seconds to load.

About 70% of the time the refresh is instant after returning to the app, sometimes I'll come back 8 hours later and swipe down to refresh and it's literally instant.

However, 30% of the time it takes *sooo* long. Maybe 30-40 seconds. It's ridiculously long, and there's no apparent reason for it.

I'm wondering if anyone knows of what might be the problem here.. If I had to guess I'd say it's because the connection to Firebase is taking a long time, but I'm not sure how I can fix that? It doesn't seem to be based on connection, either.

My code for swiping down:

```
  doRefresh(refresher) {
    this.goToNew(true);
    refresher.complete();
  }
```

and `this.goToNew()` is:

```
  this.database.database.ref('/posts/'+this.feedId)
  .orderByChild('created')
  .limitToLast(10)
  .once('value', (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach(child => {
        this.feedCounter.push(child.val());
        this.postFeed.push(child.val());
        this.postFeed.sort(function(a,b){
          return +new Date(b.created) - +new Date(a.created);
        });
        if(this.feedCounter.length >= 10) {
          this.firstRun = false;
        }
        return false;
    });
```

I have no idea what might be causing this issue... Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: It's impossible for us to say why the connection is slow on your tests. But if you [enable debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database#.enableLogging), the output may potentially give you some info to go on.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I found the solution.. I think you might be interested in seeing how I fixed the issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discovered it's actually a Firebase Authentication bug.

It fails to check the authentication of a user after returning from the background, so my fix was running `onAuthStateChanged` only after the platform is `ready`. Made the firebase connection instant!

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
       //code here
 });
});
```

Hope that helps someone as this is such an odd issue.

Comment: That's interesting Jane. So you need to reattach the auth state listener after the Ionic app comes back from being backgrounded?

Comment: Thanks, hope this will help.